# Can't access router after opening server

Tags: router, apache-http-server, ip, webserver

I have just setup a Apache server on `192.168.1.10:80` then suddenly when i try to access `192.168.1.1` the browser shows

> No Data Received

Why?, i set a server on `192.168.1.10:80` not on `192.168.1.1:80`

**Port forwarded**:

1. 80

Comment: Did you forward any ports?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, port 80

Comment: @Ramhound any help?

Comment: If you forwarded all traffic to go to a particular address that would explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forwarded port 80 from your router (.1) to your server (.10), so whenever you attempt to access port 80 on the router (.1) it's now forwarded to port 80 on the server (.10).

To fix it, turn off the forwarding of port 80, and then enter your router and change its web interface port to something other than 80 (if it allows that), THEN forward port 80 to your server.

If you can't access the router via another protocol or port (ie: https/port 443), then you may have to factory reset your router and start from scratch to get port 80 access back, so that you can access the router's web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a port forwarding rule to same port?
You cannot use port 80 in a router unless you change the admin panel of the router to be listening in other.